# Cannot add Genymotion path to PATH variable linux xubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, environment-variables

I'm following this [doc](http://docs.telerik.com/platform/appbuilder/nativescript/running-your-app/run-app-native-emulator) and trying to add Genymotion path to environment variable PATH but it's not being displayed along the others paths after running an echo $PATH.

command to add:

```
export PATH=/home/user/.Genymobile/Genymotion/
```

or:

```
export PATH=/home/user/bin:/home/user/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/local/android-studio/bin/:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin:/home/user/.Genymobile/Genymotion/
```

echo $PATH:

```
/home/user/bin:/home/user/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/local/android-studio/bin/:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin
```

I've tried to move the folder to another path but I get the same error.
How can I fix it?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this line in your ~/.profile to set `$PATH` permanently

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/user/.Genymobile/Genymotion/
```

Comment: Simply adding it to the end of the file? I'm new to linux =(

Comment: Yes, at the end (logout/login after)